# Android dragging unlimited images from the sources

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a drag and drop function in Android.I have choosed to implement it using motion event because I think it is easy to understand.I want to make that image I move to remain in the same position and move a duplication. I don't really know how to explain, I want an image on the corner and when I move it the image still remain there but I move another one that is the same, and If I want to move another one from the same position again I move another position.It's like I am trying to get 10 balls from a basket but in this case the basket and the balls are the same image.

My code so far is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private View selected_item = null;
    private int offset_x = 0;
    private int offset_y = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
            vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getActionMasked())
                    {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                    int x = (int)event.getX() - offset_x;
                                    int y = (int)event.getY() - offset_y;

            int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - 100;
            int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - 100;
            if(x > w)
                x = w;
            if(y > h)
                y = h;
                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                             lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

                                    selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);

                                    break;
                            default:
                                    break;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
       });
           ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.newwall);

            img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getActionMasked())
                    {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                    offset_x = (int)event.getX();
                                    offset_y = (int)event.getY();
                                    selected_item = v;
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    break;
                    }

                    return false;
            }
    });
```

Also, I am using a `ViewGroup` and I have a `touchListener` attached on it.When I am pressing the `Layout` I am getting the image where I press, I would like when I drop the image to remain there if I touch somewhere else on the screen.I have tried to set selected_item back to null when I end the drag but I didn't make it good I guess because I was getting error and app crashes.

Please help me solve these 2 problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have used for similar purpose

```
ImageView snapshot = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nonFullScreenSnapshot);
vg.buildDrawingCache();
cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(vg.getDrawingCache());
Drawable drawableShot = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), cache);
snapshot.setImageDrawable(drawableShot);
snapshot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In this case I have an ImageView already available from my xml layout, which should be at least as big as the image you want to duplicate.

So when the user touches your ViewGroup you should make a duplicate of it and then position it on the new location.
But be careful with the number of duplicates, because you can easily run out of memory and you will get OutOfMemory exception.